# ListView items source Binding without using mvvm

Tags: wpf, listview, data-binding

```
 public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        listView1.ItemsSource = myData; // myData is not ObservableCollection 
    }


    private void AddData_ButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        myData.Add(/*adding new item*/);
        listView1.Items.Refresh();
    }
```

and the xml code:

```
 <ListView x:Name="listView1" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"  Header="File Name"/>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding NumOfPoints}" Header="Points"/>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
  </ListView>
```

it works well, i just wanted to improve my code.for example removing Items.Refresh() method and improving the binding.
im newbie to wpf and looking for best practice advice and im not into mvvm right now.
any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: what type is `myData` if its of ObservableCollection then i believe you dont have to use `Refresh()`

Comment: No its not ObservableCollection

Comment: `List<SDRfile> files = new List<SDRfile> { new SDRfile("file1", "ok1", 11),
                                                      new SDRfile("file2","ok2",22)};`

Comment: ` class SDRfile
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
        public int NumOfPoints { get; set; }

        public SDRfile(string name, string status, int numOfPoints)
        {
            Name = name;
            Status = status;
            NumOfPoints = numOfPoints;
        }
    }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`myData` has to be an `ObservableCollection<T>` or any other type that implements the `INotifyCollectionChanged` interface for you to be able to see the added items in the `ListView` without having to reset or refresh its items collection explicitly. That's why the `ObservableCollection<T>` class exists.

So you have to the change the type of files from `List<SDRFile>` to `ObservableCollection<SDRFile>`.